# How to change the font color of a text box (Entry) using tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to know if it´s possible to change the font color of a text inside of a textbox (Entry), could you tell me if there is a certain function that I can use to change the font color of the inserted text?

```
self.t10 = Entry(self.textos, width=30)
self.t10.grid(row=11, column=1)
self.t10.insert(0,text_cifrado)
```

Comment: If you search on internet, you will get your answer easily and quickly.  Like document from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_entry.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'fg' (foreground) parameter for the Entry box.

```
self.t10 = Entry(self.textos, fg="yellow", width=30)
self.t10.grid(row=11, column=1)
self.t10.insert(0,text_cifrado)
```